# How to inject different instances of a service based on scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a directive with isolated scope, and I would like all items in that scope to get a particular implementation of a service when they get it injected. There are a couple ways I think I can accomplish the *equivalent*, but would like to know if there is a better approach:

- Not use injection at all, and instead assign the particular implementation of the service I want to $scope.myService, and have items access that member to get the service
- Have items pass $scope to the service's methods, which will vary their behavior based on what's in $scope

  I'm leaning towards the first option. But is seems that angular has the ability to inject different items based on $scope, since it does that when injecting $scope itself, and I'm wondering if I could use that mechanism somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure I've got it right, do you need to have a different service implementation injected to the directive based on where the directive is used?

Comment: @MatanHafuta - close. Inside my directive I know what the implementation should be, based on arguments passed to the directive, so I can construct the correct service inside my link function. But my directive's template has an `ng-include`, and I want all the controllers included to be injected with this instance of the service.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement you will have to create a controller dynamically using the $controller service and inject the required service in an object passed as second argument.

$controller('ControllerName', {})

You will need to attach the instance of the newly created controller to the directive's scope and use it with a ng-controller directive on your template.